# why can't i use nmake in cmd for libharu

Tags: c++, nmake

i was trying to use libharu for a project in visual studio and i needed to build the lib files using cmake so i was trying to use nmake in cmd in the script folder to build the lib files but cmd said that " 'NMAKE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " therefore it failed it even said in the libharu github instructions to type in "NMAKE -f script/Makefile.msvc" so how do i use nmake

this was the instructions i was looking at:https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation

Comment: Well, did you install it at your machine? Is msvc installed?

Comment: [Second paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-170).